# Router.push() not working without any apparent reason

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, next.js

So I'm trying to create a simple login page that redirects to another page after checking credentials and setting a cookie. My API endpoint is working fine as tested with Postman. However, for some reason `router.push` isn't working at all. It sometimes works when I mention a page that doesn't exist, giving me a 404 error. But other than that I can't figure out what's wrong with my code.

I don't see any errors on the console whatsoever either.

```
import axios from "axios"
import { useRouter } from "next/router"
import { useState } from "react"

export default function login() {

    const [username, setUsername] = useState(null)
    const [password, setPassword] = useState(null)
    const [error, setError] = useState(false)
    const router = useRouter()

    const handleClick = async () => {
        try {
          await axios.post("http://192.168.0.112:3000/api/login", {
            username,
            password,
          });
          router.push("/admin");
        } catch (err) {
          setError(true);
        }
      };
    

    return (
        <div className="container mt-5 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <h1 className="display-3">Admin login</h1>
            <form className="bg-light p-3">
                <div className="mb-3">
                    <label htmlFor="username" className="form-label">Username</label>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" id="username" onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)} name="username" aria-describedby="emailHelp"/>
                </div>
                <div className="mb-3">
                    <label htmlFor="password" className="form-label">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" className="form-control" id="password" onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)} name="password"/>
                </div>
                {error &&<span>Wrong Credentials</span>}
                <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={handleClick}>Log in</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

This page checks the credentials (from an `env.local` file) and creates a cookie if the credentials are right, but that's about it. Any idea how I can get `router.push` to start working as expected?

P.S here's the `admin` page's code. This is the page the login page is supposed to redirect to should the login be correct.

```
import axios from "axios"
import { useState } from "react"

export default function index({ products }) {

    const [productList, setProductList] = useState(products)

    const handleDelete = async (id) => {
        try {
            const res = await axios.delete(`http://localhost:3000/api/products/${id}`)
            setProductList(productList.filter((product) => product._id !== id))
            console.log(res)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <h1 className="display-3 text-center my-5">Admin Dash</h1>
            <div className="d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div className="col-md-4">
                    <form action="">
                        <div className="my-3">
                            <label htmlFor="productName" className="form-label">Enter Product Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="productName" className="form-control" id="productName" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="my-3">
                            <label htmlFor="productDesc" className="form-label">Enter Product Description</label>
                            <input type="text" name="productDesc" className="form-control" id="productDesc" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="my-3">
                            <label htmlFor="productPrice" className="form-label">Enter Product Price</label>
                            <input type="number" name="productPrice" className="form-control" id="productPrice" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="my-3 d-flex justify-content-center">
                            <button className="btn btn-primary btn-lg me-3">Upload Image</button>
                            <button className="btn btn-success btn-lg">Add Product</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr />
            <div className="d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
                <h1 className="display-3 my-3">Listed Products</h1>
                <table className="table table-striped mb-5">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Product ID</th>
                            <th scope="col">Product Name</th>
                            <th scope="col">Product Description</th>
                            <th scope="col">Product Price</th>
                            <th scope="col">Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {productList.map(product => (
                            <tr  key={product._id}>
                                <th scope="row">{product._id}</th>
                                <td>{product.title}</td>
                                <td>{product.desc}</td>
                                <td>{product.prices[0]}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <button className="btn btn-warning me-3" onClick={() => alert("Test")}>Update</button>
                                    <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={() => handleDelete(product._id)} >Delete</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        ))}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export const getServerSideProps = async (ctx) => {

    // const myCookie = ctx.req?.cookie || ""

    // if(myCookie.token !== process.env.TOKEN){
    //     return{
    //         redirect:{
    //             destination:"admin/login",
    //             permanent: false,
    //         }
    //     }
    // }
    const productsList = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/api/products")

    return {
        props: {
            products: productsList.data
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the router config?

Comment: Where would I get that? @KonradLinkowski

Comment: You have to have router to make routes in the app or something like this

Comment: I'm using Next.js so routes are already taken care of for me. This is the first time I'm using Router anyway @KonradLinkowski

Comment: _"API endpoint is working fine as tested with Postman"_ - is it working fine when you make the request from the app, though? If the `axios.post` request fails for some reason, `router.push("/admin")` won't get called. The issue is most likely not with `next/router`, but with the axios request.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure of that. Any way I can test that request from within the app? The way I see it on the front end is I click the login button and the page just refreshes with the entered data appended in the URL. @juliomalves

Comment: As in, it doesn't go to the `admin` page, but stays on the current one? Can you please share the code for the `admin` page if that's the case.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I've added the code for the admin page. @juliomalves